# Pandas series do not store data but pointers to data. What is its internal implementation?

Tags: python, pandas

While trying to store simple integer elements in series, I find that it stores index information in addition to the data items. Hence, my question on how is series internally implemented.

```
# import pandas, pd is an alias
import pandas as pd

# Creating a numeric pandas series
s = pd.Series(2)
print(s)
print(type(s))
```

The output that I get for the above operation is:

```
0    2
dtype: int64
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Comment: Refer [source-code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.24.1/pandas/core/series.py#L102-L4379)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F37fV0uFf60 maybe helpful, I think this is a little too broad to get a great/concise answer... but maybe someone will answer.

Comment: very useful video as well as the source code